# Is this sentence gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Telling my intention of when I was searching for a post on Facebook is challenging because it might sound silly.

Answer (score 1):

It has something of constructional maze. I have thought of this keeping, as far as practicable, your construction as it is.

- Telling my intention of searching for a post on Facebook is challenging because it might sound silly.

Comment: but is "something of when subject xxx" grammatically correct?

Comment: *Telling my intention...** is not idiomatic. Although we use tell both in the sense of informing people and relating stories, **telling an intention** sounds very odd indeed.

Comment: So what do you think the ideal form of it would be like?